# Different results from Hash.each and Hash.inject implementations

Tags: ruby, each, inject

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting different results from two expressions which I would have thought were functionally identical.

The `each` method:

```
matches = {}
@entries.each do|entry, definition|
    matches.merge!({entry => definition}) if entry.match(/^#{entry_to_find}/)
end
matches
```

The `inject` method:

```
@entries.inject({}) {|matches, (entry, definition)| matches.merge!
({entry => definition}) if entry.match(/^#{entry_to_find}/)}
```

The `each` code block is giving the correct answer when run, but `inject` keeps returning`nil` and I don't understand why. I'd hoped to use inject because it's a much shorter piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `if` will return `nil` in case the condition is not satisfied, and that will be used for the value of `matches` in the next iteration. Use [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) instead:

```
@entries.each_with_object({}) do |(entry, definition), matches| 
  matches.merge!({entry => definition}) if entry.match(/^#{entry_to_find}/)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm in a car at the moment, but as soon as I'm back home I'll take a detailed look at what you're suggesting.

Comment: Ok, going to select this as my answer because it explains the cause of the issue. But `select` is definitely the way for me to go. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think [ndn's analysis of why your `inject` approach doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32287503/674064) is correct. As for shorter alternatives, as you want those *unmodified* key-value pairs of `@entries` that fulfill your condition, have you considered [`Hash#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-select)?

```
matches = @entries.select { |entry, definition| entry.match(/^#{entry_to_find}/) }
```

Comment: I didn't even think about what OP was doing. `Hash#select` is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: Select might work; I think I was on an inject streak because I'd found some good uses for it recently. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a shot as soon as I get back home.